# C++: Simple Node/Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

In the following Linked List I am trying to implement a print function. The function is templated, and is not a part of the Node class.

Basically I want this print function to be dynamic, so that I don't have to print out all of the `Node->data` manually. I am kind of working along the lines of this example: http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/cpp/cpp17.php

However, when I try to implement the print function I get compiler errors such as:
`node was not declared in this scope`, `p' was not declared in this scope`, and `variable or field 'print' declared void`.

Here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
 public:
        Node(T = 0);
        ~Node() { delete [] nextPtr; };

        T getData() const;
        Node<T>*& getNextPtr() { return nextPtr; };

 private:
        T data;
        Node<T> *nextPtr;    
};

//CONSTRUCTOR   
template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T newVal)
     : data(newVal), nextPtr(NULL)
{
    //EMPTY       
};

//GETDATA() -- RETURN DATA VALUE
template<typename T>
T Node<T>::getData() const
{
      return data;

};

//PRINT FUNCTION
template<typename T>
void print(node<T>* p)
{
     while(p)
     {
             cout << p->data();
             p = p->link();        
     }
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> intNode1(5),  intNode2(6), intNode3(7);

    intNode1.getNextPtr() = &intNode2;
    intNode2.getNextPtr() = &intNode3;

    print(&intNode1);

    system("pause");   
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typo mistake. It should be `Node<T>* p` instead of `node<T>* p` in your print function. EDIT: Actually, you have more errors than that. EDIT2: Just noticed you're returning reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues, you mistyped `Node` and you are not using the interface correctly, this will compile:

```
template<typename T>
void print(Node<T>* p)
{
     while(p)
     {
             cout << p->getData() << std::endl;
             p = p->getNextPtr();        
     }
}
```

Added `std::endl` to make sure you see output. Also the way you are using the class your destructor will be calling `delete` on non dynamically allocated data. Since `intNode2` and `intNode3` are allocated on the stack. You are also using array delete `delete []` you should be using `delete`. This is potential fix for `main`:

```
int main()
{
    Node<int> intNode1(5) ;

    Node<int> *nPtr = intNode1.getNextPtr() = new Node<int>(6);
    nPtr->getNextPtr() = new Node<int>(7) ; 

    print(&intNode1);

    system("pause") ; // This is not portable
}
```

Comment: Okay, it is now set like this, and WORKS. Except when I try to exit the program it says that Node.exe has stopped working. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with my destructor....

Comment: @Ericafterdark Yes, it does, I just updated my answer

Comment: In my destructor I now have `delete nextPtr;`, but the program still crashes.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Yes because you are deleting non dynamic memory, added a new version of main

Comment: So basically the difference here is that you create new Nodes by using the getNextPtr() function?

Comment: @Ericafterdark The difference is that I am using `new` to create a dynamically allocated `Node` while your original code was taking the address of using `&` of a stack allocated variable.

Answer (score 1):

you print function:

```
template<typename T>
void print(node<T>* p)
```

should be:

```
template<typename T>
void print(Node<T>* p)
           //^^^^
```

Since there no `node` class template defined in your code.

EDIT: there are no `link()` and `data()` defined in Node class.

Comment: there is also no `data()` or `link()` methods in the `Node` class, either. print() should be calling `getData()` and `getNextPtr()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeap, agreed.

Comment: I see. I guess I never changed it to work specifically for my program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to type `Node` rather than `node`, seeing as you use `Node<T>` everywhere else...